# How to fix openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I tried to DES encryption a Query String but it give this error.

```
<?php
class DES
{
    var $key;
    var $iv;
    function DES( $key, $iv=0 ) {
        $this->key = $key;
        if( $iv == 0 ) {
            $this->iv = $key;
        } else {
            $this->iv = $iv;
        }
    }

    function encrypt($str) {
        return base64_encode( openssl_encrypt($str, 'DES-CBC', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv  ) );
    }

}
?>

$str="method=GetUserStatusDV&Key=01234567789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDE&Time=20150101012345&Username=abd12345"; // for example
    $key = 'ZyXw4321'; // for example
    $crypt = new DES($key);
    $mstr = $crypt->encrypt($str);
    $urlemstr = urlencode($mstr);
    echo "[ $str ] Encrypted: [ $mstr ] UrlEncoded encrypted string: [ $urlemstr ]";
```

openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended

Comment: What version of PHP is this?

Comment: I use PHP 7.4.29, I try to use this in my Laravel 8 app

Comment: The example you have in your question works even if deprecated

Comment: I don't know if PHP 7.4 is really what is used here. Using a constructor that has the same name as the class was deprecated since PHP 7 and then removed in PHP 8. The deprecation warning in Laravel is treated as a fatal error so the line `new DES($key);` should not be working in Laravel, the fact that this is not the line that threw the error tells me that you're more likely using PHP 8. Regardless you need to stop using legacy style constructors (i.e. functions with the same name as the class name) and use the `public function __construct(...)` function instead

Comment: Obligatory caution: DES is insecure, and this was understood 40 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are using a deprecated way to instantiate your class (using same name instead of __construct method) the sample code you provided is working.

You can improve your class like this.

```
class DES
{
    private $key;
    private $iv;
    public function __construct(string $key, string $iv = '') {
        $this->key = $key;
        if(strlen($iv) != 8) {
            $this->iv = \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(8);
        } else {
            $this->iv = $iv;
        }
    }

    public function encrypt($str) {
        return base64_encode( openssl_encrypt($str, 'DES-CBC', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv  ) );
    }

}
```